# Notation for probability of either sign

Tags: probability, functions, notation

I have a function $f(k) = \pm 2^k$ with probability $1/2$ of either sign. How would I express this in a cleaner notation? I'm guessing to use the Kronecker delta somehow, but I can't put a finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try $f(k)=2^kX_k$ where $X_k$ is a symmetric Bernoulli random variable (this means that $\mathbb P(X_k=+1)=\mathbb P(X_k=-1)=\frac12$).

Comment: I like this idea as you've managed to one-line it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 cases?
\begin{align}
f(k)&=\cases{+2^k\qquad w.p.\;1/2\\-2^k\qquad w.p.\;1/2}
\qquad k\in \text{Whatever}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for something more elegant but I'll give you an upvote once I have the reputation score >_<;